# Why are all things in Objective-C created by * lower case?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring

I'm really confused about this thing. In any tutorial, code on github and documentation I have seen BOOLs, NSStrings, NDDictionaries etc all start in lower case. Eg. NSString *aString Is this necessary? Will anything get ruined if I use upper-case while creating BOOLs etc? I'm really confused here :P Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Will using an **underscore** and then declaring variables in Capitals be a good idea?

Comment: Why are you confused? Have you encountered any problems or difficulties? Have you *tried* anything yourself?

Comment: I did try and although nothing wrong came on the console I just wanted to double check with the experts...... :)

Comment: Its more of a coding standards thing. I have just taken my SCJP exam and they have an entire chapter on coding standards. Its up to the programmer how they develop there code but think about the person who has to make amendments to it. Will using capitals make it easier to read or just make it harder. My recommendation is to stick with the coding standards as most developers understand them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Added from comments**

Its more of a coding standards thing. I have just taken my SCJP exam and they have an entire chapter on coding standards. Its up to the programmer how they develop there code but think about the person who has to make amendments to it. Will using capitals make it easier to read or just make it harder. My recommendation is to stick with the coding standards as most developers understand them.

Also under coding standards you would normally Have your Classes declared with a capital and variables starting with lower case. This is so it doesn't confuse other developers when make amendments and more importantly so it doesn't confuse you. It wouldn't be good if you got confused by your own code.

But standards say it should be like this :

```
 NSString *nsString; // Not that you should be having a variable like this. But stops the any confusion.
 [nsString uppercaseString];
```

it would start to get confusing if you had this

```
 // Compile won't actually let you have this just an example of confusion and reserved words. 
 NSString *NSString;
 [NSString uppercaseString];
```

In coding standards must experienced developers know that anything starting with a capital is generally a class and anything starting with lower case is a variable. This is in almost all programming languages. I did see a bit of confusion around coding standards when studying `prolog`.

Like Sun, Apple have there coding standards [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: Thank you! This is the most in-depth answer i have found on this question @Popeye

Comment: @iHackerMe No problem. Its always good to know good coding standards early as it can save a lot of time and confusion in the future. Good luck with improving your programming skills.

Answer (score 7):

It's just a style issue. Nothing will get ruined by using capitals, except perhaps your reputation among people who follow that style.

Comment: So I can create stuff using capitals? Thanks because I really couldn't find any answers to this question except for here @Wooble!

Comment: The compiler largely doesn't care what you name your variables (which isn't to say it's a good idea.)

Answer (score 2):

Its one of the coding conventions in Cocoa.

There is a document about [Coding Guidelines For Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) on the Apple site.

It's useful to follow these conventions. Not only because it makes your code easier to be read by other Cocoa Developers, but also because the modern LLVM compiler relies on these conventions sometimes, and you'll be getting compiler warnings for things you'll think are false positives rather than because of your unconventional code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common standard helping you to differentiate between classes and instances of classes / variables.

Different languages use different standards but you should always use the style common for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

it's called camelBack Notation. Ruby guys like underscore_notation, iOS camelBack. Though in my opinion it also makes it easier to distinguish objects (camelBack) from classes (capital).

Answer (score 0):

This is just **style or standard** of **Objective-C**. You can also declared your variables like this -

```
BOOL  MyVariable;
```

It would also work, but it would create a confusion b/w a class name and variable name this is not friendly code. So we use proper `rule` for declare **variables**.