# Button in uiview not clickable

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

Pls help.. i have this button in my subclass, when i addsubview it in my uiview, it cant be clicked, any idea?..thanks

the button in my subclass:

```
- (void)configureDate{
    ChangeButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ChangeButton.frame= CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
    [ChangeButton setTitle:@"Change Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ChangeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:ChangeButton];
}
```

I added the subclass/button in my uiview:

```
dateClass = [[DateClass alloc] init];
[dateClass configureDate];
[myView addSubview:dateClass];
[dateClass releaseTable];
```

the button appears but is not clickable:(

Comment: You really shouldn't be using an initial upper case letter for variable names. Upper case initial letters are used to denote Class names. Have you set the `myView.userInteractionEnabled` to NO? If so that will cause this problem. Also, what is dateClass? Is it a subclass of NSDate?

Comment: Are you sure that your parent view's frame is correct?

Comment: check on the top of the dateClass view or ChangeButton any other view is adding like overlay. along with the above checking.

Comment: i used dateClass to add the subclass DateClass in my uiview

Comment: Agreed with Fogmeister about upper case letters for variable names. Please see answer here for an understanding on naming conventions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495008/why-are-all-things-in-objective-c-created-by-lower-case/12496319#12496319

Comment: i actually have two buttons in my uiview, the one added directly to it is working fine, but the one coming from a subclass is not working,,

Comment: Oh... subclass of what? You shouldn't be subclassing UIButton. If you are doing that then don't. This will cause a whole world of pain for you. If you think you need a subclass of UIButton then what you should probably be doing is using a custom UIView and giving that a UIButton. Out of interest, why are you subclassing UIButton? What do you need to do that UIButton won't do?

Comment: the truth is,, the subclass is intended for a uitableview...but the table view is also not working, not clickable and is not scrollable.. so i tried to add a button to test if it will be clickable but same thing as the table view,, i guess it has something to do with adding table view class to my uiview?:(

Comment: Ah, you should have said. It's always better to state what your actual problem is rather than change things. Buttons in tableviews need a couple work arounds. See here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561831/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell-did-not-call-the-action

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[myView addSubview:dateClass];
[myView bringSubviewToFront:dateClass];
```

Try setting BG color for both dateClass and the ChangeButton button to test.

```
- (void)configureDate{
ChangeButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
ChangeButton.frame= CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
[ChangeButton setTitle:@"Change Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ChangeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:ChangeButton];
self.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
ChangeButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

}
```